# Spring Security Invalid CSRF token found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an Angular front end with Spring MVC + Spring Security backend and I'm getting the following error in my log:

```
DEBUG csrf.CsrfFilter Invalid CSRF token found for https://localhost:8443/rest/logout
```

To set up Spring Security with Angular I followed the Spring Boot tutorial below and made it fit to my application, which is already written in Spring MVC and Spring Security not Spring Boot: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Here's the relevant files:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <!-- Log4j configuration loading -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Bootstrapping context loading -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/gravytrack-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/gravytrack-services.xml
            /WEB-INF/gravytrack-security.xml
           </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>gravytrack.root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- session management listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <!-- session times out if no activities for 30 minutes -->
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--<servlet-mapping>-->
        <!--<servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>-->
        <!--<url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>-->
    <!--</servlet-mapping>-->

    <!-- Security entry point -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.html
    </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**gravytrack-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
                            secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" requires-channel="https"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/"/>
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="gtBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

        <custom-filter ref="csrfHeaderFilter" after="CSRF_FILTER"/>
        <csrf token-repository-ref="csrfTokenRepository" />

        <logout logout-url="/rest/logout" logout-success-url="/rest/login?logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

    </http>

    <beans:bean id="csrfTokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
        <beans:property name="headerName" value="X-XSRF-TOKEN" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <!--<password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>-->
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT EMAIL as USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED FROM USER_ACCOUNT WHERE EMAIL = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT EMAIL as USERNAME, AUTHORITY FROM USER_AUTHORITY WHERE EMAIL = ?"/>

            <!--<user-service>-->
                <!--<user name="admin@admin.com" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>-->
            <!--</user-service>-->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**CsrfHeaderFilter.java**

```
@Service("csrfHeaderFilter")
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());

        if (csrf != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                cookie.setPath("/rest");

                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I when I make a http post call to `/rest/logout` I receive a 403 Forbidden error in the browser along with the CSRF error in the log that I posted above.

If I host my Angular app as static content on the dispatcher servlet and (in the web.xml) change the url pattern from `/rest/*` to `/` along with the Spring Security entry point to `/*` then it works. The CSRF token passes through the filter fine and nothing goes wrong.

This makes me believe that by changing dispatcher servlet url pattern and the security entry point to `/rest/*` it messes with the CSRF cookies in some way but I don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced that "Invalid CSRF token found" error in Spring.
It was strange for me because host and port was not changed in my requests (only paths).
I'll try to debug the reason some day, meanwhile this temporary disabling of csrf can help you, be aware it may reduce security of your app:

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
           // ............
           .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: it does disable CSRF protection which is a bad idea, unless you're really sure that you don't need CSRF protection.